# Are dead people unhappy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have quite a few dead bodies littered around the place. I am aware that for people forced to work next to them, it has a severely detrimental effect on their happiness. However, do the corpses' happiness affect overall happiness? If I revive someone (and they come to life with 0% happiness), will that make my overall happiness go down?

I'm concerned because I have a review coming up.

Answer (score 1):

No, they won't have 0% happiness.  For me, some of them have around the same percent they had before dying and other seem to have 50% but they get higher really fast.

In any case, leaving them dead won't help you at all for the review because the **people around will actually become to have 0% happiness** (or close to 0%) and this is much worse, especially for a room full of people. If you are concerned for the dead people, just revive them and have them get laid :)  Raises morale immediately!

Comment: But what if I don't have any people in the same rooms? Do the dead people still count towards my overall happines

Comment: Hmm, I never tried this but it shouldn't count. If you already have an empty room with dead people inside you should be able to tell if the happiness counts or not among the total. But like I said, I don't think this is a good strategy. If you still have at least 30 min until the review you can easily make everyone happy again provided you have enough living chambers.

Comment: But I don't have enough caps to revive everyone :(

Comment: Also the review is not based just on happiness but other things like resources, rooms... and dead people might count as well (negatively)

Comment: Yeah, it's bad when you don't have enough caps... I think one way to quickly make caps is to rush production on rooms that have a low rush percentage. Otherwise, don't worry about the review, just concentrate on improving the situation without taking rash decisions. Concentrate on completing objectives